# cognos-using If statement -Issue with measure

Tags: if-statement, reporting, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I am creating a report in Cognos Report Studio 10, using an if-statement
for displaying a Column chart. On the X-Axis I am using an if-statement as follows:

```
if (?Category?='Valve Material')
then ([Relational Model].[Catalog Elements].[Valve Material]) 

else 
(if (?Category?='Valve Trim Characteristic')
then ([Relational Model].[Catalog Elements].[Valve Trim Characteristic])

else
([Relational Model].[Catalog Elements].[Valve Rating]))
```

and year in the series
and in measure I have given Sales Quantity.

This resulted in the following warning:

> RQP-DEF-0578 A grand total will be returned for measure 'Component Sales Qty' in expression 'total([Presentation Layer].[Measure].[Component Sales Qty]

It's displaying the total value of sales quantity for all the inputs.

What changes should be done on the measure to get the individual sales quantity?